# How can I align links to the bottom in grid column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've a web page that displays a list of items using bootstrap 5 grid.  Each column in the grid contains one item, and each item will have an Edit link.  I'm wanting the Edit link to be positioned at the bottom of the column.  I've tried align-bottom and bottom-0.  But none of them work. In the example below, you should see that the Edit link on the second column is not at the bottom of that column.  What am I doing wrong? (I've also tried position-absolute)

https://jsfiddle.net/hockchailim/5mgfkoLc/2/

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col p-3 rounded border text-center">
            <div class="fw-bolder">
                Item 1
            </div>
            <div>
                Desc Line 1
            </div>
            <div>
                Desc Line 2
            </div>
            <div>
                Desc Line 3
            </div>
            <a href="http://localhost:8000/products/1/edit" class="align-bottom">Edit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col p-3 rounded border text-center">
            <div class="fw-bolder">
                Item 2
            </div>
            <div>
                Desc Line 1
            </div>

            <a href="http://localhost:8000/products/2/edit" class="align-bottom">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use responsive flexbox:

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col p-3 rounded border text-center">
        <div class="fw-bolder">
          Item 1
        </div>
        <div>
          Desc Line 1
        </div>
        <div>
          Desc Line 2
        </div>
        <div>
          Desc Line 3
        </div>
        <a href="http://localhost:8000/products/1/edit" class="align-bottom">Edit</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col p-3 rounded border text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <div class="fw-bolder">
          Item 2
        </div>
        <div>
          Desc Line 1
        </div>

        <a href="http://localhost:8000/products/2/edit" class="align-text-bottom">Edit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Using the `d-flex` class to transform into flex items and `flex-column` to define the direction of the items, you just need to use the `justify-content-between` class to align the items vertically and distribute them evenly inside the container along the main axis

Comment: That kind of work.  I see that the Edit link on column two is now at the bottom.  But the Desc Line 1 on column two is being repositioned to the middle.  Is there a way to leave Desc Line 1 where I've it originally?  I only want the Edit link to be repositioned to bottom.

Comment: If you want to pin the Edit link at the bottom just keep the `d-flex` and `flex-column` classes and add the `mt-auto` class from the link. Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/

Comment: That caused all the Desc Lines to have no break line.  https://jsfiddle.net/hockchailim/5mgfkoLc/6/

Comment: But that happened because you used `d-column` instead of `flex-column`

Comment: excellent.  that work.  Thank you. https://jsfiddle.net/hockchailim/5mgfkoLc/7/